# Show columns not in GROUP BY clause without applying aggregate function on it

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I know the question was asked before, but I might have a different case, 
I have this table :

```
|  PK_DATA  |  EVENT_TYPE  |  DATE   |
-------------------------------------
|  123      |  D           |  12 DEC |
|  123      |  I           |  11 DEC |
|  123      |  U           |  10 DEC |
|  124      |  D           |  11 JAN |
|  124      |  U           |  12 JAN |
|  125      |  I           |  1 JAN  |
-------------------------------------
```

I want a query to give `max(DATE)` grouped by `PK_DATE` and at the same time give the corresponding `EVENT_TYPE` .... i.e. :

```
|  123  |  D  |  12 DEC |
|  124  |  U  |  12 JAN |
|  125  |  I  |  1 JAN  |
```

I thought to group by `PK_DATA` and select `max(DATE)` but then the `EVENT_TYPE` wont be displayed until either apply an aggregate function to it or add it to the group clause and neither will do what I want ... any help ?

BY the way I want to avoid any nested query , I know it can be done on two steps , a nested query to group then join again the main table with the query result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but not sure yet if it's better than Husqiv's in terms of performance or not, so I will post it to spread the knowledge :

`WITH data (PK_DATA, EVENT_TYPE, "DATE") AS (
  SELECT 123, 'D', DATE'2015-12-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'I', DATE'2015-12-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'U', DATE'2015-12-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 124, 'D', DATE'2015-01-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 124, 'U', DATE'2015-01-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 125, 'I', DATE'2015-01-01' FROM DUAL)
select EVENT_TYPE, "DATE", PK_DATA 
from (select EVENT_TYPE,"DATE",DATA_ID, max("DATE") over (PARTITION BY PK_DATA) max_date
from data ) where "DATE" = max_date;`

Comment: Actually I tried both ... they were very close to each others in performance but this one was 'slightly' better (11.5 s vs 12 s)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `KEEP` clause, it's significantly faster and less resource intensive than running window function (if your data set is larger):

```
WITH data (PK_DATA, EVENT_TYPE, "DATE") AS (
  SELECT 123, 'D', DATE'2015-12-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'I', DATE'2015-12-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'U', DATE'2015-12-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 124, 'D', DATE'2015-01-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 124, 'U', DATE'2015-01-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 125, 'I', DATE'2015-01-01' FROM DUAL)
SELECT
  PK_DATA,
  MAX(EVENT_TYPE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY "DATE") EVENT_TYPE,
  MAX("DATE") "DATE"
FROM
  data
GROUP BY
  PK_DATA
```

EDIT: Here is comparison between `ROW_NUMBER` and `KEEP`:

```
PANELMANAGEMENT@panel_management> set autot trace stat
PANELMANAGEMENT@panel_management> SELECT
  2     INVOICEDATE,
  3     MAX(CREATED) V1,
  4     MAX(TOTALCOST) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ORDER_ID) V2
  5  FROM
  6     ORDERS
  7  GROUP BY
  8     INVOICEDATE
  9  ORDER BY
 10     INVOICEDATE;

269 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:05.03

PANELMANAGEMENT@panel_management> SELECT
  2     INVOICEDATE,
  3     CREATED V1,
  4     TOTALCOST V2
  5  FROM (
  6     SELECT
  7             INVOICEDATE,
  8             CREATED,
  9             TOTALCOST,
 10             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY INVOICEDATE ORDER BY ORDER_ID DESC) FILTER
 11     FROM
 12             ORDERS)
 13  WHERE
 14     FILTER = 1
 15  ORDER BY
 16     INVOICEDATE;

269 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:21.82
```

The `ORDERS` table has around 10 million records and 1 GB of data. The main difference is that analytic function needs to allocate much more memory because it needs to assign row number to all 10 million rows that are filtered afterwards to resulting 269 rows. Using `KEEP` Oracle knows that it needs to allocate just one row per `INVOICEDATE`. Also when you sort 10 million rows you need the memory for storing all of them. But if you need to sort 10 million rows and keep only single record for each group you can just allocate single record and when you are sorting you just replace it with the one that is greater/smaller. In this case the analytic function required around 100 MB of memory whereas `KEEP` "none".

Comment: I haven't used this before but I like it! +1 -- Quick question, is this not a window/analytic function though?

Comment: No, it's aggregate function, analytic function evaluates for each row, aggregate produces single value for entire group.

Comment: how does

 `MAX(EVENT_TYPE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY "DATE") EVENT_TYPE`

compare to 

`max(DATA_ID) over (PARTITION BY PK_DATA) max_date`

in terms of performance ?

u said that `KEEP` is better than `OVER` ..... but actually it introduces an additional ORDER which might slow down the performance ... what do u think ???

plz check my answer below

Comment: Only place this can be problematic is if there can be two event_type values for a given pk_data with the max date, and if you want to see both records in that instance.

Comment: With no ties, then this and sgeddes answers are both as good as you'll get. One does a window sort pushed rank, the other does a sort group by, both are probably too close in performance to differentiate. So go with the style that suits you.

Comment: yes exactly I tried both on real table (about 250k rows) and they were too much close to each others .... though the one using `max over` was slightly better

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `window function` for this to establish a `row_number` for each group:

```
select *
from (
   select pk_data, event_type, date, 
       row_number() over (partition by pk_data order by date desc) rn
   from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1
```

If you ties are a concern, use `rank` instead of `row_number`.